# Using @Html.ActionLink in a replace function in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I am returning data from my DB with multiple phrases. One of them being the following text : `Submitted an Idea`

I want to make the "Idea" in any an all text a hyperlink, so I want to use a replace function in my razor view to replace the word "Idea" with my Html Helper:

```
@item.RewardType.Replace("Idea", @Html.ActionLink("Idea", "ChallengeIdea", "Ideas", new { id = item.fkiIdeaId }, null))
```

I've looked around a bit but can not really find anything. Someone suggested using @Url.Action - But the issue remains the same.

How do I do this ? Or is using an Html helper the wrong way of doing this ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@Html.Raw(item.RewardType.Replace("Idea", $"<a href='/ideas/challengeidea/{item.fkiIdeaId}'>Idea</a>"))
```

Or

```
@Html.Raw(item.RewardType.Replace("Idea", "<a href=/ideas/challengeidea/" + item.fkiIdeaId+">Idea</a>"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I get the following error : `Feature 'interpolated strings' is not available in C# 5.  Please use language version 6 or greater.`

Comment: Ah I got it! You lead me in the right direction. I did the following : `@Html.Raw(@item.RewardType.Replace("Idea", "<a href=/ideas/challengeidea/" + item.fkiIdeaId + "> Idea </a>"))` Thanks man!

Comment: Yes, you also could use "+item.fkiIdeaId" instead of $.  I will add it to answer as second choose. You are welcome!)

Answer (score 0):

Html helpers are there to **help** you in general situations. When they produce more complications than value, they have no use

```
<span>Submitted an <a href="@Url.Action("ChallengeIdea", "Ideas", new { id = item.fkiIdeaId })">Idea</a></span>
```

If you have RewardType in a resource and can not use plain html, you could set RewardType to `"Submitted an <a href=\"{0}\">Idea</a>"` And use `string.format`

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use a replace. The text I provided is an example, I have different phrases returning from the DB with the word "Idea" in it, so want to replace the word "Idea" with a hyperlink on the word "Idea" - Is this possible?

Comment: @AxleWack You might want to loop through your database results and make an if statement about any mentions regarding "idea". When the if statement returns true, then use a HTML Helper actionlink with the value of the result (which would be "idea") go inside it.

Comment: If I understand your suggestion correctly, then I will be making the enter phrase a hyperlink ? I specifically want the word "Idea" a hyperlink. Wouldnt just using a replace be simpler ? Or am Is this not as simple as I think it should be ?